# How do I search for a mouse that uses Mac's built-in bluetooth?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, mouse

There are lots of wireless mice out there that work with Macs, but most require an extra USB thingy that takes up a USB port on my Macbook (and most Macbooks have few USB ports). What search terms should I use to look for a wireless mouse that uses Mac's built-in bluetooth?

P.S. I am looking for alternatives to Apple's Magic Mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These search terms: bluetooth mouse, os x

Most Bluetooth mice work well with OS X.